# Method that converts array of integers into base64 in Java

Tags: java, base64, decode, encode

the method  `String toBase64(Integer[] decimalCh)` takes an array of integers from 0 to 63 and returns an encoded string based on the base64 table:

```
private static final char b64[] = {
      'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
      'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
      'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
      'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
      'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
      'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
      'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
      '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'
  };
```

I want to implement the method so that each integer matches the index character in the table, for instance:

```
Integer[] decChar = {37, 62, 37, 43, 0}
String result = toBase64(decChar);
```

output: l+lrA

I tried to implement it by making a nested loop but it seems that it is not an accurate approach

```
public static String toBase64(Integer[] decimalCh) {
      String result = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < decimalCh.length; i++) {
          for(int j = 0; j < b64.length; j++) {   
                  result += b64[j];

          }
      }
    return result;
```

Comment: What language and framework are you using? What have you tried so far, and how did that work or not work? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I already added my approach implementation

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to iterate through the `b64` table. Just look up the entry for each integer value in `decimalCh`. Also, you should use a `StringBuilder` rather than append to the string itself each time through the loop. Something like this should work:

```
public static String toBase64(Integer[] decimalCh) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer i : decimalCh) {
        result.append(b64[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```